# Event handling for button

Tags: android

I have created a button. Now I want to do:

1. A single click of a button will open a dialog.
2. Double click of a button will open a dial pad.
3. OnLongtouchpress of buttons I want to change the color of the button.

Now in my case, I have used a single click event. So I want to know is there any option for double click and onlongtouchpress event on the same button if so, please suggest to me. With examples, if it is possible.

Regards
Anshuman

Comment: accept some of your previously asked questions to get response from other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use   `button.setOnLongClickListener` to handle onLongclick event

For double click event See the followig URL

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/

Comment: Actually like setClick and setOnlongClick is there no function for double click in buttons

Answer (score 0):

You need to set specify listeners.

```
Button btn = (Button)findVieByID(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(.....);
btn.setOnLongClickListener(.....);
```

setOnDoubleTapListener not existing for Button

Comment: yeh both are working fine..thanks..so are you sure that there are no events for double click..

Comment: Yes, the Double Click Listener for Button is not available. But this should helps you to fix this issue http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html